# Android Scrolling views above image

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll, android-linearlayout

I want to create a screen like Viber's profile screen. So,There is an image in top of screen and bottom of image some views(linearLayout or ListView). When scrolling from image , the image must grows up and when stop touching it must be return its before size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following library .. it think this what exactly what you want..

https://github.com/ideaismobile/AKParallax-Android

Comment: thanks for your help, but i cant explain absolutely , i want , when i scrolling the image where is located top of screen, must be bigger, come from back, and grows up.

Comment: yes, i tried, and thanks for example. but it isn't exactly what i want. again i say , when scrolling the image , it must be grows , not pull-to-refresh, if image before 1x, during scrolling  2x,4x . do you understand me ?

Comment: I understand your problem dude, but you are not understand the example.. we can do that effect by setting parallax.setViewsBounds(1.3) to imageview..it clearly mentioned in example.. i dnt why u are not understand this ..